# included php "template" moved downwards

Tags: php, html, css

Edit: Fixed, moved `<?php include(haeder.php); ?>` to the top and replaced the outsourced part with `<?php showheader(); ?>`.

I've been creating a little website, and as its menubar started to get full I wanted to "outsource" it to a separate file.

```
<body>
    <div style="width:800px;margin:0px auto">

    <!-- outsourced part -->
    <div style="height:50px;background-color:#ff0000">
    Header
    </div>
    <!-- end of outsourced part -->

        <div style="margin-top:10px;background-color:#00ff00">
            hello world
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So I copied the outsourced part and pasted it into a new file called `header.php` and replaced it with

```
<?php include("header.php") ?>
```

so now the code is

```
<body>
    <div style="width:800px;margin:0px auto">

        <?php include('header.php') ?>

        <div style="margin-top:10px;background-color:#00ff00">
            hello world
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now when I open the website again the header and everything after it has moved downwards. How can I prevent this from happening? I have PHP 5.6.14 installed on XAMPP and PHP 5.3.3 on a Linux server.
Uploaded the 2 files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3b6f2n6elwzk65y/AAByIMjZMuyS9cWfQQTQns1La?dl=0)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you didn't forget something when copying, like the closing `</div>` tag or anything?

Comment: and what else does the file that calls `include` have in it?

Comment: I did exactly what I described in the beginning. If i compare the Sourcecode of the website in Firefox they are competely identical. Also if i inspect the element, there is no additional formatting

Comment: Where have you included your header file. at the top or at the end

Comment: Did you miss the closing body tag?

Comment: no it is the website, i am not yet familiar with the formatting

Comment: just to avoid further questions like the one above (i understand why you were asking): i ran the source code i got from firefox through a validator and got 0 errors.

Comment: Can you post your exact header.php code after the split?

Comment: I uploaded the 2 files, maybe I just made a very newby mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your file and I could see the issue. Usually this is because you got an invisible character in the page. So go into the Chrome debugger, Elements view, and expand the code. You'll find the following before your header `<div>` tag.

```
"
&#65279;"
```

from the debugger, you can delete it, and you'll see your page displays fine again. So cleanup your 2 php file. One is having an invisible character.

I believe the reason is that your index.php file in UTF8-BOM encoded while the header.php is just UTF8 - make sure to use the same encoding to avoid these issues.

Comment: That may have been the case in the real envoirement, too , but my .css file was the only one encoded in UTF8 without BOM, but the fix I addet to my original post worked before I noticed that. Edit: tested it, your fix works, too, when I set all the files to UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: I just noticed: as a german this was not the fix i was looking for, because it messes up all the `öüäß` characters.